# html - hyperlink and link text extraction

Tags: regex, sed, grep

Hi I'm trying to extract the hyperlink and link text

HTML

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td class="beginner">
      B03&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry">Simple Symmetry</a>  </td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
  <td class="beginner">
    B04&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </td>
  <td>
      <a href="http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase">Faces and a Vase</a> </td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
    <td class="beginner">
      B05&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing">Blind Contour Drawing</a> </td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
    <td class="beginner">
        B06&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b06/seeing-values">Seeing Values</a> </td>
</tr>
```

Code

```
sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b06/seeing-values
```

Desired

```
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry Simple Symmetry
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase Faces and a Vase
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing Blind Contour Drawing
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b06/seeing-values Seeing Values
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be setting `RS` to `<a href="[^"]*">[^<]*` regex and in main program, checking if RT is NOT NULL and using split to split its value into array arr with delmiter of `>` OR `"`, if all conditions are met then simply printing 2nd and 4th values of array arr as per requirement to get needed output.

```
awk -v RS='<a href="[^"]*">[^<]*' '
RT && split(RT,arr,"[>\"]"){
  print arr[2],arr[4]
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` with its `-E` option(to enable ERE, extended regular expressions) please try following code. Using `-n` option to stop default writing by `sed` for lines. Then in main program using `s` option to perform substitution operation. Where I am mentioning `[[:space:]]+<a href="([^"]*)">([^<]*).*` regex which will create 2 capturing groups from which we are substituting whole matched text and then using `p` option to print this matched part as per requirement.

```
sed -E -n 's/[[:space:]]+<a href="([^"]*)">([^<]*).*/\1 \2/p' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `awk`'s `match` function where mentioning regex and creating 2 capturing group to fetch the required value(s).

```bash
awk '
match($0,/^[[:space:]]+<a href="([^"]*)">([^<]*)/,arr){
  print arr[1],arr[2]
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Lacer, could you please do let me know if this has work out for you? cheers.